# Check username availability ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As the title says, I am trying to check if a username exists in the DB in a registration form using Ajax.

I use the following script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //the min chars for username
    var min_chars = 3;

    //result texts
    var characters_error = 'Minimum amount of chars is 3';
    var checking_html = 'Checking...';

    //when button is clicked
    $('#user_id').keyup(function(){
        //run the character number check
        if($('#user_id').val().length < min_chars){
            //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '
            $('#username_availability_result').html(characters_error);
        }else{
            //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check
            $('#username_availability_result').html(checking_html);
            check_availability();
        }
    });

});

//function to check username availability
function check_availability(){

    //get the username
    var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

    //use ajax to run the check
    $.post("db.php", { user_id: user_id },
        function(result){
            //if the result is 1
            if(result == 1){
                //show that the username is available
                $('#username_availability_result').html(user_id + ' is Available');
            }else{
                //show that the username is NOT available
                $('#username_availability_result').html(user_id + ' is not Available');
            }
        });

}
```

and my *db.php* file looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "signup") {
$user_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_id"]);
$new_password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["new_password"]));
$new_email    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["new_email"]);
$checking_existance=mysqli_query($str,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$user_id."'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($checking_existance);
print_r($checking_existance);
if(mysqli_num_rows($checking_existance)>0)
 {
    echo 0;
 }
else{
    echo 1;
}
```

}

The problem I am encountering is that the result is always showing that the *username* is not available even if it is.

Comment: MD5 is not secure.  You should use bcrypt.

Comment: It makes no sense to hash an escaped string.

Comment: `action` is not being passed in your `ajax` call

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the warning, I will look at that after I solve my problem!

Comment: @AlexP, exactly, because it always takes the *else* statement. Any idea why?

Comment: @Suvimo I don think your even entering the conditional statement, `action,new_password and new_email` are required but no passed via the post

Comment: @Suvimo - add some error checking. Make sure that your SQL statements are running correctly.

Comment: @AlexP, actually `action` is retrieved as a hidden parameter when the button "sign up " is clicked, so it is actually set. `new_email` does not affect really, as it is not used to get any result!

Comment: @andrewsi, I did, and it seems that the query is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful for you.You can check for your solution on the following link [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971495/username-availability-check-using-ajax-and-php-against-mssql) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839934/check-username-availability-issue?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `db` file is looking for a number of `$_POST` variables that you have not passed in.

`action, new_password and new_email`

I would guess that if you did `console.log(result)` you would get `undefined`, therefore its not `= 1` and therefore goes into the else statement.

You need to change the `AJAX` call to:

```
$.post("db.php", { 
  user_id: user_id, 
  action: action, 
  new_password: new_password,
  new_email: new_email
}, ...
```

Comment: Further to this, the OP is printing the whole result via `print_r($checking_existance);`, so the result is never going to be 0 or 1

Comment: Why would I need to pass the password and the email if I am not using them to get the result? 
The `if` statement in the db.php does not need `new_password` neither `new_email` to execute!

Comment: @Suvimo You are using them! not in the query but the page is using `POST` variables that you are not posting, meaning an error!

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis - `print_r($checking_existance);` Will never run, the `AJAX` call does not pass `action`, therefore `$_POST['action']` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

just do it in an easy way `(i found that there is no action, new_password and new_email parameters in your javascript )` please take care of that too.

**Javascript**

```
var min_chars = 3;
var characters_error  = 'Minimum amount of chars is 3';
var checking_html = 'Checking...';
var xhr_request = false;
var usernames = {};

$(function() {
  $("#user_id").on("keyup", check_availability );
});

function check_availability() {
  if ( xhr_request ) {
    xhr_request.abort();
  }
  var user_id = $.trim( $(this).val() );
  if ( !user_id || user_id.length < min_chars ) {
    $("#username_availability_result").html( characters_error );
    return;
  }

  // check user_id exists in runtime cache, to avoid useless requests :\
  if ( usernames[user_id] !== undefined ) {
    if ( usernames[user_id] === true ) {
      //show that the username is available
      $("#username_availability_result").html( user_id+" is Available" );
    }
    else {
      //show that the username is NOT available
      $("#username_availability_result").html( user_id+' is not Available' );
    }
    return;
  }

  //use ajax to run the check
  xhr_request = $.post( "c.php", { 'action' : 'validate', 'user_id' : user_id } );
  xhr_request.success(function( result ) {
    //if the result is 1
    if ( result == 1 ) {
      // add user_id to cache
      usernames[user_id]  = true;
      //show that the username is available
      $("#username_availability_result").html( user_id+" is Available" );
    }
    else {
      // add user_id to cache
      usernames[user_id]  = false;
      //show that the username is NOT available
      $("#username_availability_result").html( user_id+' is not Available' );
    }

  });
  xhr_request.fail(function() {
    $("#username_availability_result").html( "connection error, please try again" );
  });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if ( isset( $_POST["action"] ) && isset( $_POST["user_id"] ) ) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db" );
    $userid = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST["user_id"] );

    if ( $_POST["action"] === "validate" ) {
      $result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '{$userid}'" );

      if ( $result && $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        echo "0";
      }
      else {
        echo "1";
      }
    }
    elseif ( $_POST["action"] == "signup" ) {
      // do the process
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: thank you! but how is this simpler than mine? You are using almost the same approach!

Comment: and why is `new_password` and `new_email` needed at this level? we are not using them to retrieve the results!

Comment: no, not in this, i mean in your php code, you are searching for that parameters and i didnt saw anything in your javascript file.